# Sorting hash values by length of lines in a text files

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

Read line in *file1*, if line not exist in *file2* write this line to the new file .
Comparison is made by the length of the hash string .

Hash values ​​in *file1*:

```
cf03189f5b05eb1a9658f80d7a0e9f02:_#.g}
edbe6de8b3ee19b45e092147f57af7b8:]mNon
47253940f843f258ffd265d13f365d70:/u'yv
5701aa8e2aa7e1cfd16ca4076bd1732a:@AQ1z
b3c0866e6fd56776bc4a18d3c87cc725:t$5OV
7a1e6090568e076c55df9dc7abf356c6:9rC@p
04046da33706518d9b15a38bcddb448e:!DFPk
```

Hash values ​​in *file2*:

```
edbe6de8b3ee19b45e092147f57af7b8:]mNon:str1
47253940f843f258ffd265d13f365d70:/u'yv:2str
b3c0866e6fd56776bc4a18d3c87cc725:t$5OV:3str1ng
```

This is a working example written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 80
typedef enum {FALSE=0,TRUE=1} BOOL;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE   *fpin1 = NULL;
    FILE   *fpin2 = NULL;
    FILE   *fpout = NULL;
    char   line [LINE_LENGTH]={0};
    char   line1[LINE_LENGTH]={0};
    BOOL   bCheck = FALSE;
    size_t ncHash = 0;
    size_t count = 0;

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage:%s <file1> <file2> <OutFile>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    /*
      Opening input files (file1 and file2) for reading in text mode.
      The output file (OutFile) is open for writing.
    */
    if(((fpin1=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL) ||
       ((fpin2=fopen(argv[2],"r"))==NULL) ||
       ((fpout=fopen(argv[3],"w"))==NULL))
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open files\n");
        return 1;
    }    
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fpin1)!=NULL) /* Read hash line from the first file1 */
    {
        bCheck=FALSE;
        while(fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), fpin2)!=NULL) /* Read hash line from the second file2 */
        {
            if(!strncmp(line, line1, 38)) /* Compares 38 characters of the line in file1 to those of the file2 */
            {
                bCheck=!bCheck;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!bCheck) /* Does compared line are the same ? */
        {
            fputs(line,fpout); /* Yes - write them in a file OutFile */
            ncHash++; /* Count identical lines */
        }
        rewind(fpin2); /* Seek to the beginning of the file2 */
        count++;      /* Counting the read lines in file1 */
    }
    printf("\nDone...\n");

    fclose( fpin1);
    fclose( fpin2);
    fclose( fpout);
    return 0;
}
```

The *OutFile* from the program is:

```
cf03189f5b05eb1a9658f80d7a0e9f02:_#.g}
5701aa8e2aa7e1cfd16ca4076bd1732a:@AQ1z
7a1e6090568e076c55df9dc7abf356c6:9rC@p
04046da33706518d9b15a38bcddb448e:!DFPk
```

---

- I want to know how to write it in `awk`?

Comment: Look at the `comm` or `join` standard unix utilities.

Comment: `join -v1 all <(cut -d: -f1,2 excludes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2];next}!(($1,$2) in a)' excludes.txt all.txt
```

Note the reversal of file argument order.

An explanation:
`-F:` - use `:` as a field separator
`NR==FNR` - The first file (current row number = total row number)
`a[$1,$2]` - Touch the array at the first two fields
`next` - move on to the next line, so we don't have to check the alternate `NR != FNR` condition
`!(($1,$2) in a)` - check whether the combination was seen. If not, print the line (default action)

Comment: Does not work for me `(awk -W version:
GNU Awk 3.1.8
Copyright © 1998, 1991-2010 Free Software Foundation.)
` : outputs 7 lines..

Comment: Works on mac/bsd awk, I'm checking but try replacing `$1,$2` with `$1":"$2` both places.

Comment: Works on GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0

Comment: script work properly, but must be careful with spaces.
For example if you copy/paste lines directly from html form, some empty spaces will be added at end of line and result will be incorrect. 
 @xtof pernaud solution does not suffer from this inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 'sµ(.*):.*$µ\\§\1§dµ' file2 |sed -f - file1
```

Because of the many 'ugly' characters the code is for info only, do not use in production.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean `awk`. It's possible to do it, but it will eat 2 times the files sizes of memory:

```
cat file1 file2 |
awk '{ s = substr($0, 1, 38); str[NR] = s; ex[s]++; } 
END {
       for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
          s = str[i];
          if (ex[s] == 1)
             print s;
       }
}'
```

Output:

```
cf03189f5b05eb1a9658f80d7a0e9f02:_#.g}
5701aa8e2aa7e1cfd16ca4076bd1732a:@AQ1z
7a1e6090568e076c55df9dc7abf356c6:9rC@p
04046da33706518d9b15a38bcddb448e:!DFPk
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl

```
perl -F: -ane'BEGIN{$f=$ARGV[0]}print if$ARGV ne$f&&!$h{$F[0]};$h{$F[0]}=1' file2 file1
```